# The spectrum of a semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, semiring

One of the generalizations of algebraic geometry is provided by the theory of semiring schemes, viz. [Lorscheid 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3261). The theory follows the same set up of scheme theory, but we use [semirings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) instead of rings, also known as rings without additive inverses; examples of which are the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or the tropical semiring $\mathbb{T}$.

An *ideal* of a semiring $R$ is a set $I\subset R$ which 1) is closed under addition 2) contains $0$, and 3) is such that $IA=I$. Moreover, $I$ is *prime* if whenever $ab\in I$, then $a\in I$ or $b\in I$, and we write $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ for the set of prime ideals of $R$.

---

What are $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{T})$? Do we have other nice examples of prime spectra of semirings?

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ doesn't even have many ideals in the first place – it's like a field. There is a natural identification of the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the prime ideals of $\mathbb{N}$, but it is an interesting exercise to find a prime ideal of $\mathbb{N}$ that is not just the intersection of a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{N}$. (There is at least one, and if I recall correctly it is the only one.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, that's true. Is $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{N})=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\cup(2,3)$?

Comment: The ideal generated by $\{ 2, 3 \}$, i.e. $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 1 \}$, is indeed prime. As far as I know that is the only extra prime ideal but I don't remember why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's compute $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{N}$. Certainly $p\mathbb{N}$ is a prime ideal for every positive prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, and you can check that both $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ are prime ideals. As @Zhen Lin points out in the comments, these are in fact the only prime ideals of $\mathbb{N}$; to see why, suppose $P$ is a non-zero prime ideal of $\mathbb{N}$. Then there exists some non-zero natural number in $P$; if $P$ contains $1$, then $P=\mathbb{N}$, a contradiction. So $P$ contains a natural number greater than one, and hence must contain one of its prime factors $p$. If every element of $P$ is divisible by $p$, then $P=p\mathbb{N}$. Otherwise $P$ contains an element outside of $p\mathbb{N}$, and hence must contain one of its prime divisors $q$, which is necessarily distinct from $p$. By the "[coin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)", $P$ now contains every number greater than $pq-p-q$. In particular, for any $n>1$, there exists some $k$ such that $n^k>pq-p-q$, whence $n^k\in P$ and so $n\in P$. So $P=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$, as desired.

Now let's compute $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{T}$. By convention, I take $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, with $\oplus$ as $\min$ and $\otimes$ as $+$. Note that $\{\infty\}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{T}$; I claim it is the only one, and that it is in fact the only *proper* ideal of $\mathbb{T}$. To see this, suppose that $I$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{T}$ containing some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $I\ni\lambda\otimes x$ for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{T}$. In particular, for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $I$ contains $(y-x)\otimes x=y$, and furthermore $I$ contains $\infty\otimes x=\infty$. So $I=\mathbb{T}$, a contradiction. Thus indeed $\{\infty\}$ is the only prime ideal of $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: ＠AtticusStonestrom Thank you!

Comment: @Sofia my pleasure, happy it helped! :)